# Display the content of a struct

Tags: c#, reflection, struct

I am trying to display the contents of a struct like so

```
private void GetEntityInfo(FieldInfo fieldInfo, Entity entity)
{
     if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsNested)
     {
         // THIS PART IS WRONG!
         //foreach (var field in fieldInfo.GetType().GetFields())
         //{
         //    GetEntityInfo(field, entity);
         //}
     }
     else
     {
         var info = new EntityInfo
         {
             Index = (int) Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(Entity), fieldInfo.Name),
             Name = fieldInfo.Name,
             Value = fieldInfo.GetValue(entity).ToString()
         };
         EntityInfoList.Add(info);
     }
}
```

The struct has nested structs inside.  How do i go about getting the fields for a nested struct?  If it is not nested the values come out as expected. Something like.

```
struct Entity
{
   int c;
   Something something;
   int d;
   int e;
}

struct Something
{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

Comment: You want to get the type of the field - running `GetType()` on a  `FieldInfo` instance is going to return `FieldInfo`, not the type that the field represents. Try `FieldInfo.FieldType` instead. e.g. `foreach (var field in fieldInfo.FieldType.GetFields())`

Comment: This can cause an infinite loop if you have cycles on your structs. i.e. `struct Entity { Entity anotherEntity; }`